# Parse a penn syntax tree to extract its grammar rules

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, nlp

I have a PENN-Syntax-Tree and I would like to recursively get all rules that this tree contains.

```
(ROOT 
(S 
   (NP (NN Carnac) (DT the) (NN Magnificent)) 
   (VP (VBD gave) (NP ((DT a) (NN talk))))
)
)
```

my target is to get the grammar rules like:

```
ROOT --> S
S --> NP VP
NP --> NN
...
```

As I said I need to do this **recursively and without the NLTK Package or any other modules or regular expression**. Here's what I have so far. The parameter `tree` is a Penn-Tree splitted on each space.

```
def extract_rules(tree):
    tree = tree[1:-1]
    print("\n\n")

    if len(tree) == 0:
        return

    root_node = tree[0]
    print("Current Root: "+root_node)

    remaining_tree = tree[1:]
    right_side = []

    temp_tree = list(remaining_tree)
    print("remaining_tree: ", remaining_tree)
    symbol = remaining_tree.pop(0)

    print("Symbol: "+symbol)

    if symbol not in ["(", ")"]:
        print("CASE: No Brackets")
        print("Rule: "+root_node+" --> "+str(symbol))

        right_side.append(symbol)

    elif symbol == "(":
        print("CASE: Opening Bracket")
        print("Temp Tree: ", temp_tree)
        cursubtree_end = bracket_depth(temp_tree)
        print("Subtree ends at position "+str(cursubtree_end)+" and Element is "+temp_tree[cursubtree_end])
        cursubtree_start = temp_tree.index(symbol)

        cursubtree = temp_tree[cursubtree_start:cursubtree_end+1]
        print("Subtree: ", cursubtree)

        rnode = extract_rules(cursubtree)
        if rnode:
            right_side.append(rnode)
            print("Rule: "+root_node+" --> "+str(rnode))

    print(right_side)
    return root_node


def bracket_depth(tree):
    counter = 0
    position = 0
    subtree = []

    for i, char in enumerate(tree):
        if char == "(":
            counter = counter + 1
        if char == ")":
            counter = counter - 1

        if counter == 0 and i != 0:
            counter = i
            position = i
            break

    subtree = tree[0:position+1]

    return position
```

Currently it works for the first subtree of `S` but all other subtrees are not getting parsed recursively. Would be glad for any help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My inclination would be to keep it as simple as possible and not try to reinvent the parsing modules that you're currently not allowed to use.  Something like:

```
string = '''
    (ROOT
        (S
            (NP (NN Carnac) (DT the) (NN Magnificent))
            (VP (VBD gave) (NP (DT a) (NN talk)))
        )
    )
'''

def is_symbol_char(character):
    '''
    Predicate to test if a character is valid
    for use in a symbol, extend as needed.
    '''

    return character.isalpha() or character in '-=$!?.'

def tokenize(characters):
    '''
    Process characters into a nested structure.  The original string
    '(DT the)' is passed in as ['(', 'D', 'T', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ')']
    '''

    tokens = []

    while characters:
        character = characters.pop(0)

        if character.isspace():
            pass  # nothing to do, ignore it

        elif character == '(':  # signals start of recursive analysis (push)
            characters, result = tokenize(characters)
            tokens.append(result)

        elif character == ')':  # signals end of recursive analysis (pop)
            break

        elif is_symbol_char(character):
            # if it looks like a symbol, collect all
            # subsequents symbol characters
            symbol = ''

            while is_symbol_char(character):
                symbol += character
                character = characters.pop(0)

            # push unused non-symbol character back onto characters
            characters.insert(0, character)

            tokens.append(symbol)

    # Return whatever tokens we collected and any characters left over
    return characters, tokens

def extract_rules(tokens):
    ''' Recursively walk tokenized data extracting rules. '''

    head, *tail = tokens

    print(head, '-->', *[x[0] if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in tail])

    for token in tail:  # recurse
        if isinstance(token, list):
            extract_rules(token)

characters, tokens = tokenize(list(string))

# After a successful tokenization, all the characters should be consumed
assert not characters, "Didn't consume all the input!"

print('Tokens:', tokens[0], 'Rules:', sep='\n\n', end='\n\n')

extract_rules(tokens[0])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Tokens:

['ROOT', ['S', ['NP', ['NN', 'Carnac'], ['DT', 'the'], ['NN', 'Magnificent']], ['VP', ['VBD', 'gave'], ['NP', ['DT', 'a'], ['NN', 'talk']]]]]

Rules:

ROOT --> S
S --> NP VP
NP --> NN DT NN
NN --> Carnac
DT --> the
NN --> Magnificent
VP --> VBD NP
VBD --> gave
NP --> DT NN
DT --> a
NN --> talk
```

**NOTE**

I changed your original tree as this clause:

```
(NP ((DT a) (NN talk)))
```

seemed incorrect as it was producing an empty node on a syntax tree grapher available on the web so I simplified it to:

```
(NP (DT a) (NN talk))
```

Adjust as needed.

Comment: first of all thx for the answer, it seems to work mostly, could you maybe explain or comment the crucial parts of the code? Also the extract rules method is giving me a error:   ```File "nnn.py", line 52, in read_treebank
    extract_penn_rules(tokens[0])
  File "nnn.py", line 88, in extract_penn_rules
    print(head, '-->', *[x[0] if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in tail])
  File "nnn.py", line 88, in <listcomp>
    print(head, '-->', *[x[0] if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in tail])
IndexError: list index out of range```

Comment: secondly some of my POS-Tags contain dashes '-' and the tokenize method seems to split those in to multiple heads:
e.g: ```[['S', ['NP', 'SBJ', ['EX', 'There']], ['VP', ['VBZ', 'is'], ['NP', 'PRD', ['DT', 'no'], ['NN', 'asbestos']], ['PP', 'LOC', ['IN', 'in'], ['NP', ['PRP', 'our'], ['NNS', 'products']]],
['ADVP', 'TMP', ['RB', 'now']]], []]]```
'PP' and 'LOC' should be 'PP-LOC'

Comment: @SaifDeen, I've added the dash handling though that is something you could trivially add yourself.  SO is here to help you get past road blocks, not handle all the finishing details  I've commented my code to help explain my logic.  As far as the `extract_rules()` issue, provide me with example input that raises the error and I'll see what I can do.  Also, you didn't comment on my syntax note.

Comment: ty so much for you help. I could have done the dash handling after I saw that but to be honest: I worked now for a week on that issue and I have lost the overview on it. About your note: I'm not sure its just one of many penn trees I need to parse. I think you fixing it was right.

Comment: About the error on `extract_rules`, this was my input: `( S ( NP-SBJ ( EX There ) ) ( VP ( VBZ is ) ( NP-PRD ( DT no ) ( NN asbestos ) ) ( PP-LOC ( IN in ) ( NP ( PRP$ our ) ( NNS products ) ) ) ( ADVP-TMP ( RB now ) ) ) ( . . ) )`

Comment: oh, `extract_rules()` works now as I have added some characters that also were in my penn tree.. Could you add this line to your answer at `is_symbol_char`: `return character.isalpha() or character in "-=$!?."`

Comment: one last thing: Could you explain to me those two lines ? `head, *tail = tokens; print(head, '-->', *[x[0] if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in tail])`
What does the asterisk do at the list comprehension

Comment: @SaifDeen, in `head, *tail = tokens` asterisk is an unpacking operator such that `a, *b = [1, 2, 3]` puts `1` into `a` and the rest `[2, 3]` into `b`.  This is new with Python 3 -- since you have the [Python-3.x] tag set, I felt safe using it.  In the `print()` statement, the asterisk performs a different unpacking operation which is `print(*[a, b, c])` -> `print(a, b, c)`.  I.e. it unpacks the list into the arguments.

Comment: @SaifDeen: Do consider accepting this answer. It's brilliant.

Comment: This answer is seriously underrated

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in a much simpler manner. Given we know the structure of our grammar is CNF LR, we can use a recursive regular expression parser to parse the text.

There's a package called pyparser (you can install it with `pip install pyparser` if you don't already have it).

```
from pyparsing import nestedExpr

astring = '''(ROOT 
(S 
   (NP (NN Carnac) (DT the) (NN Magnificent)) 
   (VP (VBD gave) (NP ((DT a) (NN talk))))
)
)'''

expr = nestedExpr('(', ')')
result = expr.parseString(astring).asList()[0]
print(result)
```

This gives

```
['ROOT', ['S', ['NP', ['NN', 'Carnac'], ['DT', 'the'], ['NN', 'Magnificent']], ['VP', ['VBD', 'gave'], ['NP', [['DT', 'a'], ['NN', 'talk']]]]]]
```

So we've successfully translated our string into a hierarchy of lists. Now we need to write a little code to parse the list and extract rules.

```
def get_rules(result, rules):
    for l in result[1:]:
        if isinstance(l, list) and not isinstance(l[0], list):
            rules.add((result[0], l[0]))  
            get_rules(l, rules)

        elif isinstance(l[0], list):
            rules.add((result[0], tuple([x[0] for x in l])))
        else:
            rules.add((result[0], l))

    return rules
```

As I mentioned, we already know the structure of our grammar, so we've only to take care of a limited number of conditions here.

Call this function as such:

```
rules = get_rules(result, set()) # results was obtained from before

for i in rules:
   print i
```

Output:

```
('ROOT', 'S')
('VP', 'NP')
('DT', 'the')
('NP', 'NN')
('NP', ('DT', 'NN'))
('NP', 'DT')
('S', 'VP')
('VBD', 'gave')
('NN', 'Carnac')
('NN', 'Magnificent')
('S', 'NP')
('VP', 'VBD')
```

Order this as you need.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cant use any modules or regular expression. I should have said that :(

Comment: Well, you might want to say it now to prevent wasting anyone else's time.

Comment: Well, if you can figure out how to parse the string to obtain a list, you can extract rules with `get_rules`.

Comment: Is there a way maybe to extend my function to parse also the other subtrees?